# Distinguish if C++ object was dynamically allocated or not?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Memory for a C++ object can be allocated during compile-time (on the stack).

```
MyClass mc;
```

Or dynamically (the common approach)

```
MyClass *mc = new MyClass();
```

Is there any method **built into** the C++ language that allows one to distinguish if a object was allocated in a static or dynamic manner?  By built into I mean though the use of templates, or keywords, etc (a non-programmed/algorithmic approach).

Essentially the goal is to 'mark' an object that was not allocated with the `new` operator (dynamic allocation).

Comment: Nothing is ever allocated at compile time, unless you count some `constexpr` stuff.

Comment: Important note: *Classes* aren't allocated; *instances of classes* (a.k.a. *objects*) are.

Comment: Are you asking how to recognize if something was allocated on the heap? You can acheive that with an overload of `operator new`

Comment: @StoryTeller: Not really, you might have an object with auto storage that is allocated in the heap if it is part of a larger object, or if it was not directly allocated with new (say a call to `::operator new` followed by placement new --sounds awkward? think `std::make_shared`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As StoryTeller says, what you probably want is to overload the `new` operator.

```
class A{
    private:
        bool isDynamic;

    public:
        void *operator new(size_t size){
            isDynamic = true;
        }
```

Comment: Almost. I think the OP wants to catch _all_ heap allocations. That means the global `operator new` must be overriden. Also, your exmple is flawed since `operator new` only returns a pointer to raw memory.

Comment: Maybe, but the way I interpreted his question was that he was talking about a specific class. He may need to clarify a bit more.

Comment: I added one more line to clarify. Overloading the `new` operator is actually a good approach as classes not allocated using `new` will have a bool value of `false`.

Comment: @ParkerKemp If I overloaded the `new` operator of a base class, could this method still work if essentially the `new` operator of the derived class is being called?  How could the base class know if the class was allocated using `new` or not?

Comment: This is just semantics btw, but you should learn the difference between "class" and "object". I'm sure you understand the concepts, but it's important to distinguish between the two when communicating with others about it.

Comment: Also note that `operator new` is there to *allocate* memory, not to set the value of that memory. A compiler could decide to initialize that memory (say in debug mode) after your `operator new` completes and your constructor is called. Additionally, if you implement `operator new` you need to implement `operator delete`, and you should probably implement `operator new[]` and `delete[]`

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible to detect whether an object has been allocated statically or dynamically. At least in the sense that most people use those words: stack vs. heap. The C++ standard considers three types of storages, *static* storage (global variables, static members of classes, static local variables), dynamically allocated and auto storage.

It is the third one that complicates things, as an object with *auto* storage might be allocated as part of a larger object that might be allocated in either of the three arenas. Consider for example an object allocated in the heap and managed by a `shared_ptr`, it might have been allocated directly with `new`, or it might have been created through `make_shared`. In the first case, there is a call to `new` with your type, but in the latter, a larger block is dynamically allocated and the object is constructed in place:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> p = std::make_shared<T>();
std::shared_ptr<T> q( new T() );
```

Now the interesting point is *why* do you care how the object was created, as there might be different things that can be done to solve your real *problem* that don't involve what you are asking for.